# I am trying to check if the phone number format is correct

Tags: java, string

The phone numbers that I will check have two formats:

`(555) 555-5555` and `555-555-5555`

However, my if condition keeps failing in the code below. I am trying to check if the `str.charAt(0)` is a `(` or a number

```
public static boolean isPhoneNumber(String str) {
    if (str.contains("-")) {
      for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
        if ((i == 0 && str.charAt(0) != '(')
            || (i == 0 && Character.isDigit(str.charAt(0)) == false)) {
          System.out.println(Character.isDigit(str.charAt(0)));
          return false;
        }

        if (i == 4 && str.charAt(4) != ')' || i == 4 && !(Character.isDigit(str.charAt(4)))) {
          System.out.println("here2");
          return false;
        }

        if (i == 3 && str.charAt(3) != '-'
            || i == 3 && (Character.isDigit(str.charAt(3)) == false)) {
          System.out.println(str.charAt(3));
          return false;
        }

        if (i == 5 && str.charAt(5) != ' ' || i == 5 && !(Character.isDigit(str.charAt(5)))) {
          System.out.println("here4");
          return false;
        }

        if (i == 7 && str.charAt(i) != '-' || i == 7 && !(Character.isDigit(str.charAt(i)))) {
          System.out.println("here5");
          return false;
        }

        if (i == 9 && str.charAt(9) != '-' || i == 9 && !(Character.isDigit(str.charAt(9)))) {
          System.out.println("here6");
          return false;
        }

        if (i != 0 && i != 3 && i != 5 && i != 7 && i != 9 && !(Character.isDigit(str.charAt(i)))) {
          System.out.println("here7");
          return false;
        }
      }
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  }
```

Comment: There are a number of regular expressions you can use, but just beware, phone number formats aren't standardised (well) and change between country and even states within some countries, and you can have short cut variations - it's really a mess 

Comment: Look at what you've written - "IF it's not a parenthesis OR it's not a digit, THEN ...".  This condition will always be true, because everything is either not a parenthesis or not a digit.  Also, there's nothing in your method that ever returns true.

Comment: Why is this in a loop if you’re only checking the first character?

Answer (score 1):

A general regex pattern which might work here is:

```
^(?:\(\d{3}\)\s*|\d{3}-)\d{3}-\d{4}$
```

Here is an explanation of the above regex:

```
^               from the start of the input
(?:
    \(\d{3}\)   match (xxx)
    \s*         followed by optional whitespace
    |           OR
    \d{3}-      xxx-
)
\d{3}-\d{4}     match xxx-xxxx
$               end of the input
```

### Demo

This would cover both versions of the phone number you gave above.  In Java, we can use `String#matches` here:

```
String phone1 = "(555) 555-5555";
String phone2 = "555-555-5555";

if (phone1.matches("(?:\\(\\d{3}\\)\\s*|\\d{3}-)\\d{3}-\\d{4}")) {
    System.out.println(phone1 + " is in a valid format");
}

if (phone2.matches("(?:\\(\\d{3}\\)\\s*|\\d{3}-)\\d{3}-\\d{4}")) {
    System.out.println(phone2 + " is in a valid format");
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  My phone number checker works very well. Can you tell me how your regex works since I am quite new to regexes in Java?

Comment: I have added an explanation of the regex.